# How to calculate dynamic table each row total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the transaction statement and in that,I am adding the credit amount of each table tr and trying to show in balance column and in case of debit deduct from balance and show in the balance column but when I am trying to achieve these its showing balance as infinity. Please see my snippet and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#cbtn-selectors tr').each(function() {
    var cr = Number(parseFloat($('.cr').text()));        
    var dr = Number(parseFloat($('.br').text()));             
    if (!isNaN(cr) && cr.length !== 0) {
        sum = Number(parseFloat($('.total').text()));
        sum = sum + cr;
    } else {
        sum = Number($('.total').text());
        sum = sum - dr;
    }
    $('.total').html(sum);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cbtn-selectors" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Contest name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Cr amount</th>
            <th>Dr amount</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>cr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>27th Dec 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>dr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>01st Jan 1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>cr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>28th Dec 2018</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="crt"> </span></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="drt"> </span></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="collectedt"> </span></th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I figured out here is the answer it might help someone

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#cbtn-selectors tr').each(function(){
                var cr = Number(parseFloat($('.cr', this).text()));
                var dr = Number(parseFloat($('.dr', this).text()));
                var sum = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('.total', this).text();
               
                var total;
                if (cr !== 0) {
                    sum=Number(sum);
                    total = sum + cr;

                } else {
                    sum=Number(sum);
                    total = sum - dr;
                    //console.log(total);
                }
                $('.total', this).html(total);
            });
});
```

```css
.total{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cbtn-selectors" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Contest name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Cr amount</th>
            <th>Dr amount</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>cr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>27th Dec 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>dr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>01st Jan 1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>cr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>28th Dec 2018</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="crt"> </span></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="drt"> </span></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="collectedt"> </span></th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look for specific element inside the `tr` you have, using `find()` on the current `tr` you are iterating (in this case: `this`). Because using `$(...)` will match all the elements with the same class and that will make your code fail on understanding which value it should use to calculate.

Please, check below code and see if it helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#cbtn-selectors tr').each(function() {

    var cr = Number(parseFloat($(this).find('.cr').text()));
    var dr = Number(parseFloat($(this).find('.dr').text()));
    var sum = 0;
    if (!isNaN(cr) && cr > 0) {
        sum = Number(parseFloat($(this).find('.total').text()));
        sum = sum + cr;
    } else {
        sum = Number($(this).find('.total').text());
        sum = sum - dr;
    }
    $(this).find('.total').html(sum);
});
});
```

```css
.total{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cbtn-selectors" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Contest name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Cr amount</th>
            <th>Dr amount</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>cr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>27th Dec 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>dr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>01st Jan 1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> new test contest</td>
            <td>cr</td>
            <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
            <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
            <td class="total">0.00</td>
            <td>28th Dec 2018</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="crt"> </span></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="drt"> </span></th>
            <th>Total:-<span class="collectedt"> </span></th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Calvin I want to take  previous row balance amount and add or deduct according to credit and debit amount

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- Typo in `$('.br')`, it should be `$('.dr')`
- You are not passing context while selecting elements hence first element matching class will be selected. In `jQuery` selector, second argument could be passed as `context` hence selection of the element will be from the provided context.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cbtn-selectors tr').each(function() {
    var cr = Number(parseFloat($('.cr', this).text()));
    var dr = Number(parseFloat($('.dr', this).text()));
    if (!isNaN(cr) && cr.length !== 0) {
      sum = Number(parseFloat($('.total', this).text()));
      sum = sum + cr;
    } else {
      sum = Number($('.total', this).text());
      sum = sum - dr;
    }
    $('.total', this).html(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cbtn-selectors" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contest name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Cr amount</th>
      <th>Dr amount</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> new test contest</td>
      <td>cr</td>
      <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
      <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
      <td class="total">0.00</td>
      <td>27th Dec 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> new test contest</td>
      <td>dr</td>
      <td class="cr"> 0.00 </td>
      <td class="dr"> 500 .00 </td>
      <td class="total">0.00</td>
      <td>01st Jan 1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> new test contest</td>
      <td>cr</td>
      <td class="cr"> 500 .00 </td>
      <td class="dr"> 0.00 </td>
      <td class="total">0.00</td>
      <td>28th Dec 2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Total:-<span class="crt"> </span></th>
      <th>Total:-<span class="drt"> </span></th>
      <th>Total:-<span class="collectedt"> </span></th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Rayon I just now checked your answer showing cr column amount in balance column but I want something like bank statement  please help me

Comment: @NithishPK - That is not mentioned in your problem statement. I am not sure what do you mean by `bank statement`..