# Calculating value based on last table td input value

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-arrays

Hie there,
I am trying to creating a dynamic account statement and when one enters an amount it should automatically calculate the balance based on the previous balance in `<td><input>`. I have tried the code below and i don't know what I am missing.
Below is my html and js code

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="invoiceItem">
                    <tr>
                      <th width="2%"><input class="formcontrol" id="checkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
                      <th width="7%">Item Date</th> 
                      <th width="12%">Item Number</th>   
                      <th width="42%">Description</th> 
                      <th width="11%">Charges (Debit)</th>                     
                      <th width="12%">Credit</th>
                     <th width="14%">Balance</th>
                      
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>
                      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control itemdate" id="itemdate_1" name="itemdate[]" type="date" required></td>
                      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control itemnum" id="itemnum_1" name="itemnum[]" type="text" required></td>
                      <td><textarea id="productDescription_1" name="productDescription[]" class="form-control"></textarea></td>
                      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity" id="charges_1" name="charges[]" type="number" required></td>
                      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control price" id="credits_1" name="credits[]" type="number" placeholder="125" required></td>
                      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control total" id="total_1" name="total[]" type="number"></td>
                      
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

Not very good in Js but did work something like this which is not returning an error, neither is it printing any value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      try {
       $("#invoiceItem tr td input[id^='charges_']").each(function() {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("charges_",'');
        var debits = Number(parseFloat($('#charges_'+id).val()));
        var credits  = Number(parseFloat($('#credits_'+id).val()));
            var sum = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('#total_'+id).val();

             var total;
                 if (debits !== 0) {
                    sum=Number(sum);
                    total = sum + debits - credits;

                } else if (credits !== 0){
                    sum=Number(sum);
                    total = sum - credits;
                    //console.log(total);
                }
                else{
                  sum=Number(sum);
                  total = sum + debits;
                }
                $('#total_'+id).val(parseFloat(total));
        });
       }
catch(err) {
  document.getElementById("noContent").innerHTML = err.message;
}
 });
```

Here is the result that i am expecting [image: statement result]

Comment: See  the HTML table as a representation of some data. So, each time new data is added, removed or changed you create the table based on the data. Maintain the data in some array or JSON object. Update the data object and based on that change the content of the table.

Comment: @chrwahl what I'm looking for is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006813/how-to-calculate-dynamic-table-each-row-total/54007104#54007104 the only difference is that my data is array data based on input value data not pre-saved saved data. Meaning as the person enters data on the inout field the TOTAL changes for example (Total+charges-credit = Total)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it, It was returning a NAN value so I solved it by using a placeholder value of 0 (value="0") in my html input